# Why is my navigation code not working? kivy python

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have a screen manager `ThirdWindow` which is supposed to change the screen when `B1` is clicked basically a navigation thing. Please note `ThirdWindow` is a a different class. `callback` is called when `B1` is clicked. it changes the screen with the help of `ThirdWindow` I think. I used `self.manager.current` it didn't worked, I also tried using it by making `ThirdWindow` a def in class `Dre` but the results were same. The print statement is not getting printed that is inside `def callback(self, instance)` so I think the def is not getting called `on_click` at all. How can I fix that? Thanks

````
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle
from kivy import platform
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass



class ThirdWindow(ScreenManager):
    def load(self):
        sm = ScreenManager
        sm.add_widget(Dre(name='Dre'))
        sm.add_widget(SecondWindow(name='SecondWindow'))
        self.sm.current = 'Dre'

class Dre(RelativeLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Dre, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.color = [254/255, 102/255, 37/255, 1]
        self.H_color = [254/255, 102/255, 37/255]
        self.sound_theme = None
        self.init_audio()
        self.kv = Builder.load_file('Levels.py')

        if platform in ('linux', 'win', 'macosx'):
            with self.canvas.before:
                self.bg = Rectangle(size=self.size, source='Neo.png')

            self.bind(pos=self.update_bg)
            self.bind(size=self.update_bg)
        else:
            with self.canvas.before:
                self.bg = Rectangle(size=self.size, source='Neon.png')

            self.bind(pos=self.update_bg)
            self.bind(size=self.update_bg)


    def update_bg(self, *args):
        if platform in ('linux', 'win', 'macosx'):
            self.bg.pos = self.pos
            self.bg.size = self.size
            self.add_widget(Label(text='D  R  E  A  M  S',
                          pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .8},
                          font_size='60dp', font_name='Roboto-Bold.ttf', color=self.H_color))
            B1 = Button(text='P L A Y', font_name='Roboto-Bold.ttf', size_hint=(.2, .15),
                     pos_hint={'center_x': .5, "center_y": .3}, background_color = self.color, background_normal='')
            # B1.bind(on_press=return self.kv)
            self.add_widget(B1)

        else:
            self.bg.pos = self.pos
            self.bg.size = self.size
            self.add_widget(Label(text='D  R  E  A  M  S',
                                  pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .8},
                                  font_size='30dp', font_name='Roboto-Bold.ttf', color=self.H_color))
            B1 = Button(text='P L A Y', font_name='Roboto-Bold.ttf', size_hint=(.2, .15),
                        pos_hint={'center_x': .5, "center_y": .3}, background_color=self.color, background_normal='',
                        on_press=self.callback)

            self.add_widget(B1)


    def callback(self, instance):
        print('working')
        self.manager.current = 'SecondWindow'

    def init_audio(self):

        self.sound_theme = SoundLoader.load('Bg_theme.mp3')
        self.sound_theme.volume = 1
        self.sound_theme.loop = True
        if self.sound_theme:
            self.sound_theme.play()
            print('okay')
        else:
            print('not okay')


class SecondWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SecondWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.color = [254 / 255, 102 / 255, 37 / 255, 1]
        if platform in ('linux', 'win', 'macosx'):
            with self.canvas.before:
                self.bg = Rectangle(size=self.size, color=self.color)





class LabApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Dre()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    LabApp().run()```




if you provide any solution please provide it in .py file.
````

Comment: What is in `'Levels.py`?

Comment: `Levels.py` is another folder with an empty class. I tried using another folder for different screens before but then moved them all into one script. So is it causing the problem? Pls help. I still can't figure out the problem

Answer (score 0):

Many issues with your code.

First, you have defined a `ScreenManager` class (`ThirdWindow`), but you have not created an instance of it or included it in your GUI. In order to use a `ScreenManager` to manage `Screens`, you must add it to your GUI. I would suggest modifying your `LabApp` class to use `ThirdWindow`:

```
class LabApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ThirdWindow()
```

and modify `ThirdWindow` to replace the `load()` method with an `__init__()` method:

```
class ThirdWindow(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ThirdWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(Dre(name='Dre'))
        self.add_widget(SecondWindow(name='SecondWindow'))
```

Since the `Dre` class is being used as a `Screen`, it must be redefined as a `Screen`:

```
class Dre(Screen):
```

and you can add the `callback` to the creation of the `B1` `Button`:

```
        B1 = Button(text='P L A Y', font_name='Roboto-Bold.ttf', size_hint=(.2, .15), on_release=self.callback,
                 pos_hint={'center_x': .5, "center_y": .3}, background_color = self.color, background_normal='')
```